# associate custom scrollbar with panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, scrollbar

I wish to make custom horizontal scrollbar that would be longer than width of panel that I would like to scroll with it. How to connect it?

```
ScrollBar hScrollBar = new HScrollBar();
        hScrollBar.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        ScrollBar.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(hScrollBar_Scroll);
        splitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Add(hScrollBar);
```

---

```
    void hScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        ?
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Just put the controls in the panel, size the form and put this code

```
panel1.AutoScroll=true;
```

after InitializeComponent
If you want a "real custom" scroll bar, do something like this:

```
hScrollBar.Maximum=700;
hScrollBar.Value=0;
hScrollBar.Scroll+=delegate (object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    int diference=e.OldValue-e.NewValue;
    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls) c.Location=new Point (c.Location.X+diference, c.Location.Y);
};
```

But you must find the maximum value, in my case aprox 700.